# Creating a custom Hibernate UserType - What does isMutable() mean?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I am creating a custom UserType in Hibernate for a project. It has been relatively straightforward until I came to the isMutable method. I am trying to figure out what this method means, contract-wise.

Does it mean the class I am creating the UserType for is immutable or does it mean the object that holds a reference to an instance of this class will never point to a different instance?

I found some examples in the [Hibernate Community Wiki](http://www.hibernate.org/37.html) where they returned true, because the object itself was mutable - http://www.hibernate.org/73.html.

Other examples in the community wiki returned false without addressing why, even though they were also mutable.

I have checked the JavaDoc, but it's not very clear either.

From the JavaDoc for [UserType](http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/usertype/UserType.html):

```
public boolean isMutable()
    Are objects of this type mutable?
    Returns:
        boolean
```

From JavaDoc for [Type](http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/type/Type.html):

```
public boolean isMutable()
    Are objects of this type mutable. (With respect to the referencing
    object ... entities and collections are considered immutable because
    they manage their own internal state.)
    Returns:
        boolean
```

Comment: Links are no longer valid fyi

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hibernate will treat types marked as "mutable" as though they could change (i.e. require an UPDATE) *without* pointing to a new reference. If you assign a new reference to a Hibernate-loaded property Hibernate will recognize this even if the type is immutable - this happens all the time with, for instance, String fields.
But if, say, you have a StringBuilder field and you mark it as *immutable* Hibernate will **not** notice if you modify the StringBuilder.

See [this blog post](http://blog.xebia.com/2009/11/09/understanding-and-writing-hibernate-user-types/) for more details and a sample project.

Answer (score 2):

The typical example here is the String class - it is Immutable, i.e. once the string is created you cannot change its contents or state, and if you want to then you're going to have to process it into a new copy.

isMutable returning true means you are saying this object can have its state changed by outside objects, returning false means you will have to copy this object to a new instance makign the changes to state along the way. Or as you said: "does it mean the object that holds a reference to an instance of this class will never point to a different instance".

Comment: In the JavaDoc for Type.isMutable(), they say to mark arrays as Immutable. But this seems to contradict what you said, since arrays can have their state changed by outside objects.