# Hiberate mapping type and saved Type

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, custom-type

I have Class CustomDate and that is referred in other class called Test.

```
public   class CustomDate{
    public String toString(){
       return "20100829"
    }
}
public class Test{
    CustomDate date;
}
```

In Mapping file of Test

```
<property name="date" COLUMN="DATE">
```

I want to save only long value and type should be long type and i should not save date object and string value.long value will be this like:"20100829" actual date:29-08-2010. Because in feature if want compare dates in sql it may create problem, if it is long value, sql compare queries will fine. Do we have any way do it in Hibernate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to implement the [`UserType`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/org/hibernate/usertype/UserType.html) interface, and define the behavior of your new type.

```
<property name="twoStrings" type="com.company.CustomDate" />
```

**Resources :**

- [Hibernate's wiki - UserType for persisting a Typesafe Enumeration with a VARCHAR column](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/UserTypeforpersistingaTypesafeEnumerationwithaVARCHARcolumn#)
- [User Types in Hibernate - Integer Date Formats](http://i-proving.com/space/Technologies/Hibernate/User+Types+in+Hibernate)
- [Hibernate documentation - Custom value types](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-types-custom)

**Related posts :**

- [Creating a custom Hibernate UserType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224481/creating-a-custom-hibernate-usertype-what-does-ismutable-mean)
- [Hibernate custom UserType isn't working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567396/hibernate-custom-usertype-isnt-working)

Comment: I totally stole it from polygenelubricants :P